# Getting bg colour of listbox element?

Tags: python, tkinter, background, listbox

Earlier in my code, I have a function that successfully changes the colour of a listbox element to gray depending if it was selected by a user. It turns gray so the user cannot reselect the same item, therefore I am trying to create a function that **gets** the bg colour of a specified index value in the listbox.

```
bground = ListboxName[index]['bg']
if bground == 'gray':
    print('bg is gray')
else:
    print('bg is NOT gray')
```

The line of code I cannot get working is: `bground = ListboxName[index]['bg']`
Any ideas? Please note I would not like to use classes...

I have also tried `bground = ListboxName[index, 'bg']` and `bground = ListboxName(index)['bg']`.

Comment: Could you please post some minimal code example which we can copy and paste and which leads to the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an option for an individual item, use `itemcget`. Assuming that your widget is named `ListBoxName`, and that you've properly computed the index of the item, it would look like this:

```
bground = ListBoxName.itemcget(index, "background")
```

Here's a complete example that will display the color when you click on an item:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def handle_click(self):
    curselection = listbox.curselection()
    index = curselection[0]
    color = listbox.itemcget(index, "background")
    label.configure(text="color: {}".format(color))

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, anchor="w")
listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
listbox.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", handle_click)

for item in range(20):
    color = random.choice(("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "white"))
    listbox.insert("end", item)
    listbox.itemconfigure("end", background=color)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It keeps saying, "TypeError: must be str, not int". Not sure if it's referring to the index or anything else... but the index has to be an int, so I don't know what it's referring to, any idea?

Comment: @JDomleo: my apologies, I gave a bad example. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you @Bryan Oakley, exactly what I needed.